# UPDATE and JOIN causing a Syntax Error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update, syntax-error

```
UPDATE default_weekly_stats s 
INNER JOIN default_profiles p
ON p.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE (default_profiles.opid = 0 OR default_profiles.opid IS NULL) 
    AND s.week = `1`
    AND s.correct_picks = `4`
SET s.rank = 1
```

That's my query and I'm getting an error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE (default_profiles.opid = 0 OR default_profiles.opid IS NULL) AND s.week = ' at line 1`

The syntax looks right to me, but clearly I'm missing something. Any ideas what?

Comment: have you tried leaving out the backticks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WHERE` comes **after** `SET`

```
UPDATE default_weekly_stats s 
INNER JOIN default_profiles p ON p.user_id = s.user_id 
SET s.rank = 1
WHERE (default_profiles.opid = 0 OR default_profiles.opid IS NULL) 
AND s.week = 1 
AND s.correct_picks = 4
```

And as @Chad mentioned: Leave the backticks. You could use quotes but don't need any delimiter for numbers.

Comment: He also does not need backticks if rank, week and correct_picks are of type `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

Try this:

```
UPDATE
  default_weekly_stats s
    INNER JOIN default_profiles p
      ON p.user_id = s.user_id 
SET s.rank = 1
WHERE (default_profiles.opid = 0 OR default_profiles.opid IS NULL)
  AND s.week = `1`
  AND s.correct_picks = `4`
```